# How to automatically get an access token for Docusign using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, docusignapi

For 2 months i've been trying to automatically get an access token from Docusign. I already have a functional (tested) API call. Is there a way to do this without manual input using GAS?

I once managed to get an authorization code using my browser with [these instructions](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/%5Btext%5D(https://stackoverflow.com)) but it only lasts for 2 mins. Even the access token lasts for only 8 hours so the only viable solution for me in this case is to generate an authorizantion code each time I make my api call.

I tried an usual GetAccessToken() code from the internet but it gives the following error: "Error: Callback function name is required."

I already created an app and integration key in my developer account, setting the URI to "http://localhost/" and authentication method to Authorization Code Grant. Can anyone help me with this? Here's the code I used (I'm using OAuth2 library):

```
function getAuthorizationCodeGrant() {
  var clientId = 'xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx';
  var clientSecret = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx';
  var redirectUri = 'http://localhost/';
  var scope = 'signature';
  var authUrl = 'https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth';
  var tokenUrl = 'https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token';

  var service = getOAuthService(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUri, scope, authUrl, tokenUrl);

  if (!service.hasAccess()) {
    var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    Logger.log('Open the following URL and authorize the script:');
    Logger.log(authorizationUrl);
    return;
  }

  // Access token is available, make API calls using the access token
  var accessToken = service.getAccessToken();
  Logger.log('Access token: ' + accessToken);

  // Use the access token to make API requests to DocuSign
  // Example API request:
  var apiUrl = 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts';
  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
    }
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, options);
  Logger.log('API response: ' + response.getContentText());
}

function getOAuthService(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUri, scope, authUrl, tokenUrl) {
  return OAuth2.createService('docusign')
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl(authUrl)
    .setTokenUrl(tokenUrl)
    .setClientId(clientId)
    .setClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .setRedirectUri(redirectUri)
    .setScope(scope);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems that in the case of DocuSign API, the access token can be retrieved by the refresh token. And also, it seems that the refresh token expires are 30 days. But, it seems that when a scope of "extended" is used, the expiration time can be removed. How about this? https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/#use-refresh-tokens Unfortunately, I cannot test this API. So, I proposed just a method for approaching and I cannot propose the correct modified script. I apologize for this. But, if you cannot use the refresh token, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

For a script scenario like this you better use [JWT](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/) and **not** [Auth Code Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/).

JWT would enable you to do everything without a browser or a user active.

However, you need to get a [one-time consent manually](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-individual-consent/), but this can be done once and you're done.